# C program array and for loop exercise

Tags: c, arrays

I have to write a function which checks if a value is located in an array with N elements using for loop.I wrote the code

```
 #include <stdio.h>
int main ()
int N[100],n,i; 
printf ("Write the value of n:");
scanf ("%d",&n);
i=0;

      printf ("Write the value of the element :");
      scanf ("%d",&v[i]);
      for (i=0,i<n,i++)
      {
          if (N[i]==n)
          }
          printf ("The value is located in the array :");



return 0;
```

When I compile it,it says syntax error before printf.What does this mean?What have I done wrong?

Comment: You need to enclose the `printf` with brackets `{ printf();}`. You also have to close the bracket for the `for` loop. And where are the brackets for the `main`?

Comment: Putting brackets around `printf` isn't going to solve this problem.  To start with, your entire `main` function needs brackets; the syntax is something like `int main () { ...code goes here... }`.

Comment: You need to spend some time with a basic book on C syntax.

Comment: Formatting code is over rated

Comment: "You need to enclose the printf with brackets { printf();}" -- please don't write ignorant nonsense.

Comment: "What have I done wrong?" -- You've submitted line noise to the C compiler instead of a syntactically correct C program.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basic syntax issues.  Try:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int N[100],n,i; 
    printf ("Write the value of n:");
    scanf ("%d",&n);
    i=0;
    printf("Write the value of the element :");
    scanf("%d", &v[i]);  /* v doesn't exist */

    /* you are looping up to n, which could be anything */
    for (i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        /* you never populate N, so why would you expect n to be found?
        the value of any element in N is indeterminate at this point */
        if (N[i]==n)
        {
            printf ("The value is located in the array :");
        }
    }      

    return 0;
}
```

---

That said, you have logical problems here:

1. `v` is not declared anywhere.
2. You never populate your array (`N`).
3. `n` is a value entered by the user, not the upper bound of the array. What if I enter 101?

Those are more than syntax issues,  you'll need to fix your logic.